# Bitnami LAMP htaccess rewrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bitnami

I'm faced with an issue with URL rewrite rules using htaccess. Basic rewrites such as...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...work perfectly, however, more advanced rewrite rules such as...

```
RewriteRule ^thread/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ thread.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^thread/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ thread.php?slug=$1
```

...don't work.

I'm using a Bitnami Virtual Machine on the Google Cloud Platform.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? By "don't work", do you mean nothing happens?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^thread/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/?$ thread.php?slug=$1
```

Not sure that the regexp gap is correct with `0-9-/`
And it may also be a problem with `MultiViews`
Works with or without / at the end.

Comment: `0-9-/` - I agree, that hyphen _in the middle of the character class_ should ordinarily be escaped in order to match a literal hyphen (assuming that is the intention). However, in this instance (on Apache 2.4), the unescaped hyphen still appears to "work as intended" - both the hyphen and slash in the character class are successfully matched as literal characters. I think this is because the hyphen does not form a valid range. Of course, we don't actually know what URL the OP is requesting, etc. (Other flavours of regex might have resulted in an error.)

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you! In this case, it is certainly not the answer to the problem. I will let him try and I will eventually delete my answer.

Comment: I think escaping the hyphen is certainly a valid point (I wouldn't delete your answer for that). However, you may have hit the nail on the head with `MultiViews` in this instance. If `MultiViews` was enabled then mod_negotiation would rewrite the request to `thread.php` (no `slug`) before mod_rewrite, so the `RewriteRule` would never match and the `slug` URL param is never set.

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks again